# Cannot parse JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this json and trying to parse it using Ajax.

```
{
    "data1": ["1 06, 2016 23:27:11", "22.4", "26.3", "866.81"],
    "data2": [
        ["1 06, 2016 21:55:39", "1 06, 2016 22:05:49", "1 06, 2016 22:15:59", "1 06, 2016 22:26:10", "1 06, 2016 22:36:19", "1 06, 2016 22:46:30", "1 06, 2016 22:56:41", "1 06, 2016 23:06:51", "1 06, 2016 23:17:01", "1 06, 2016 23:27:11"],
        ["22.1", "22.2", "22.5", "22.6", "22.7", "21.5", "22.6", "22.6", "22.5", "22.4"],
        ["25.7", "26.8", "27.1", "27.2", "27.2", "26.3", "26.9", "26.7", "26.4", "26.3"],
        ["866.9", "866.64", "866.81", "866.61", "866.53", "866.65", "866.51", "866.65", "866.67", "866.81"]
    ],
    "data3": [
        ["1 03, 2016", "1 04, 2016", "1 05, 2016", "1 06, 2016"],
        ["21.8", "21.1", "20.5", "20.3"],
        ["23.8", "24.1", "24.2", "23.4"]
    ],
    "data4": [
        ["1 03, 2016", "1 04, 2016", "1 05, 2016", "1 06, 2016"],
        ["32.7", "28", "22.9", "23.5"],
        ["35.7", "32.8", "29.5", "28.5"]
    ],
    "data5": [
        ["1 03, 2016", "1 04, 2016", "1 05, 2016", "1 06, 2016"],
        ["869.31", "870.46", "867.2", "864.37"],
        ["872.57", "875.91", "875.54", "869.3"]
    ]
}
```

After parsing, the console shows this just as it is printed from php file. However, it can not find values when I'm trying to print a specified value in the console and gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

For example when printing first value of the array inside data1 object ("1 06, 2016 23:27:11") using:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "source.php",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
    }).responseText;
console.log(jsonData);
console.log(jsonData.data1[0]);
```

Comment: What shows on console.log(jsonData.data1); ?

Comment: it returns: undefined

Comment: You are using `.responceText` and `dataType: "json"` are they compatible? After all jquery shoudl have converted it to a json object. Or maybe not in this case so you may have to manually convert the string to a json object if you are catching it as text

Comment: I think you are printing the response when the ajax petition hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: your last line should be `console.log(JSON.parse(jsonData).data1[0]);`, since _jsonData_ is still a string at that point...

Comment: @RiggsFolly: note the use of `.responseText`: it won't matter what jq does with the response, and there's no callback to pass the parsed data to anyway...

Comment: @ManuelGarcia: note the use of sync ajax...

Comment: Isn't it possible to parse JSON once and use it around the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.getJSON( "source.php", function( json ) {
  console.log(json.data1[0]);
});
```

Comment: This returns the desired value properly.

Comment: If you want to use a ajax petition I recoomend : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
but if you want make a ajax petition which return a json I reccomend:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/